# Rollback and Migrate by single command line in laravel

Tags: laravel, database-migration, rollback, migrate

after rollback `php artisan migrate:rollback --step 2` then I need to run command `php artisan migrate` . is there are any single command line for rollback and migrate ? like `php artisan migrate:fresh`

Comment: `php artisan migrate:refresh` you can try `refresh` it drops table and again migrate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may roll back & re-migrate a limited number of migrations by providing the step option to the refresh command. For example, the following command will roll back & re-migrate the last five migrations:

`php artisan migrate:refresh --step=2`

Comment: do you have any resource for laravel 8 sample project as boilerplate with learning clips or crash course for migrate and use all features as sample. briefly describe every steps we need?

Comment: I am working on a demo project of version 8 for make sure each function are working properly. Laravel V8 also similar to its previous version but small changes are occurred on last update. please let me know the questions, I can help you. Thank you